# JavaScript return not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This is a total newbie questions, and I'm trying to learn JavaScript and node.js. I'm attempting to use request to grab information from an api, and then store the information in an array that I can then manipulate.

Here is my code so far:

```
const request = require('request');
var url = "https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/ticker/CHINA.INAUGURAL.2017";
var info = request(url, function(err, res, body){
    var json = JSON.parse(body);
    return json;
})
```

However, the `info` variable seems to only store something that I think is related to the `request` call, but I'm not sure. If I replace `return json` with `console.log(json)` then it prints the array immediately, though I can't get it to store it.

I would like to tell node `info['ID']` and have it return `2835`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node does not work like this. Node is asynchronous.
You can try this,

```
 var info;
    request(url, function(err, res, body){
        info = JSON.parse(body);
    });
```

Comment: I tried that, and I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Comment: Where are you trying to access info variable?

Comment: Immediately following the request. Right now, I'm just putting it in line-by-line.

Comment: No it will not work like that. As said node is asynchronous so your request function will be called and the node will move to the next function immediately without waiting for the response of the request function.

Comment: You will have to either use promises for this or access the variable inside the request callback function.

Comment: This worked when I also made sure to specify that I wanted a JSON response, which I hadn't done before.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you' re requesting xml file from that url. You can install xml2js library for nodejs by typing npm install xml2js and let it parse the xml for you. After that

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var url = "https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/tick /CHINA.INAUGURAL.2017";
var info = request(url, function(err, res, body){
   parseString(body, function (err, result) {
       info = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
   });
   return info;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one should work,

```
request('https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/ticker/CHINA.INAUGURAL.2017', 
function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR: Something went wrong');
        }
        else {
            parseString(responce.body, function (err, result) {                    
               res.json(result);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that data is stored into 'info' variable but you're using  it before data is stored. 
Here it takes some time for API call to process and get data. Then it will be stored into 'info' variable. Have a timeout of 5s and then try console.log(info[1]) and would return expected value.
This is due to asynchronous nature of nodejs. Here your code might be executing info[1] before it is set by API call.